# ¿Cómo setear un valor String "0.000" a un tipo de Dato BigDecimal en Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, bigdecimal

Tengo un campo llamado `NoOpciones` del tipo de Dato `Bigdecimal` dicho campo debo de validarlo, si viene null le debo de setear el valor `0.000`,  tengo la siguiente validación:

```java
private static final String DECIMALES = "0.000";
BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal(DECIMALES);       
                  
if (detalle.getNoOpciones() == null) {
      details.setNoOpciones(num);
}
```

pero al mostrar el consola el valor final me muestra `0`, y quiero que salga `0.000`

¿Cómo debo de hacerlo para que se muestre correctamente?

Answer (score 1):

Recuerda establecer la escala de tu BigDecimal

```java
String DECIMALES = "0.000";
BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal(DECIMALES); 
num.setScale(3, RoundingMode.HALF_UP); //Establecemos la escala a 3 decimales y la forma de redondeo
System.out.println(num); // muestra 0.000
```

Ejemplo funcionando https://www.mycompiler.io/view/CkV5q3D